# ¿Como abrir Whatsapp o Gmail desde una APP instalada en android 12?

Tags: android-studio

Hace un tiempo hice una APP, la cual tiene dos botones, un botón para abrír whatsapp en un chat especifico y otro botón para abrir gmail con un destino, un asunto y un saludo predefinido, funcionan perfectamente. Ahora que cambie de celular (android 12) y quise instalar la APP, tuve que hacer algunos cambios para que funcionara. La APP funciona bien, pero el acceso a gmail o whatsapp ya no funcionan desde la APP a través de los botones, siempre se va por la exclusión que coloque "whatsapp no esta instalado en su teléfono" y "gmail no esta instalado en su teléfono.

Revisando encontré que en el teléfono anterior, whatsapp y gmail estan instalados dentro de la carpeta android/data (visible por la app FILE), en el nuevo teléfono (android 12) siguen allí en la carpeta android/data/ pero ya no son visible por app FILE. Tendra algo que ver eso con que ya no funcionen a traves de mi APP, faltara algún permiso en el MANIFEST.XLM o alguna librería en el BUILD.GRANDLE?

Código que uso para abrir whatsapp

```
public void abrir_whatsapp(View view) {

    String contact = "+57 5720262213"; // use country code with your phone number
    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + contact;

    app_instalada = "/com.whatsapp";

    PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app_instalada);

    if (intent == null) {
        app_instalada = "/com.whatsapp.w4b";
    }

    try {
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        pm.getPackageInfo(app_instalada, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Whatsapp no esta instalado en tu teléfono", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Código que uso para abrir Gmail

```
public void abrir_gmail(View view) {

    String nombre_paquete = "com.google.android.gm";
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(nombre_paquete);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"lina.maria@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Solicitud ");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Chicos buenas tardes, ");

    if (intent != null) {

        i.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");

    } else {

        i.setPackage("com.google.android.gm.lite");

    }

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gmail no esta instalado en tu teléfono.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

la forma en que funciona en android 12 en adelante es utilizando Intents

```
final Intent compartir = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, destinatarios)
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivos PDF")
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri) //Este es el archivo que vas a enviar
                            .setType("application/pdf");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartir, "Compartir PDF"));
```

Esto te mostrara una ventana emergente que preguntara por cual aplicacion quieres abrir. Es cuestión de elegir whatsapp o gmail

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias ya logre solucionar el inconveniente David Estrada